# Multiple certificates and key pair entries in java keystore

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, keystore, truststore

We have an application running in Server. There are multiple clients using this application. Server has a **keystore.jks** which has certificate and keypair entry.
The existing certificate(**old.xyz.com**) is getting expired soon. As a result, we have created a brand new certificate(**new.xyz.com**). We have added the new certificate and key pairs to the existing keystore.jks.

So the keystore now has the below 4 entries

1. Certificate old.xyz.com - Expiring in 1 March, 2023
2. Keypair old.xyz.com
3. Certificate new.xyz.com - Expiring in 1 March, 2024
4. Keypair new.xyz.com

Similarly on the Client **truststore.jks** we have added the servers old certificate and servers new certificate.

**Question**
How can we tell the server to present **new.xyz.com** certificate to clients as soon as **old.xyz.com** expires?

Goal is to not having clients any downtime while we deploy new certificates to Server after old certificates get expired.

[image]

Comment: How you tell a SSL/TLS server which key&cert(chain) to use depends on the program if coded explicitly, or the library(s) and/or platform(s) it uses; for example does it use Tomcat/Wildfly? Glassfish/Payara? WebSphere? SpringBoot? Something else? Nothing? In any case, I know of _no_ server that switches automatically upon expiration, rather you switch it manually at a time you select that is after all clients are ready but before the old cert (or chain) expires.